# Is there a way to convert an array in a string into a working array?

Tags: python, arrays, string, type-conversion, raw

I tried converting an array that is in a string `string = "[[(34, 66, 75), (3, 145, 74)], [(5, 78, 33), (7, 44, 6)]]"` to a working array `[[(34, 66, 75), (3, 145, 74)], [(5, 78, 33), (7, 44, 6)]]` in python but I failed. I tried so much but I couldn't think of another solution.

```
string = "[[(34, 66, 75), (3, 145, 74)], [(5, 78, 33), (7, 44, 6)]]"

arr = r"%s" %string

print(arr[1][0])

# output: (5, 78, 33)
```

I was hoping that if I manage to make the string raw I will be able to use the array in it.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is what you need - https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: @slothrop or if it's valid JSON, you can also use [**`json.loads`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `ast.literal_eval` like this,

```
import ast
string = "[[(34, 66, 75), (3, 145, 74)], [(5, 78, 33), (7, 44, 6)]]"
arr = ast.literal_eval(string)

print(arr)
print(arr[1][0])
```

**Output**:

```
[[(34, 66, 75), (3, 145, 74)], [(5, 78, 33), (7, 44, 6)]]
(5, 78, 33)
```